# mongoose.connection.useDb('projectDb') not working as expected.. still creates 'test' database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on one express server that has many projects. So far, the collections were being saved under on database for those different projects. We wanted to change that and have one database for each project so we employed this as the model format. This is just a sample for the user model for one of the projects

**userModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["user", "moderator", "editor", "admin"],
    default: "user",
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Name is Required"],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, "Email is not valid"],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  mobile: {
    type: String,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 8,
  },
  passwordChangedAt: Date,
  passwordResetToken: String,
  passwordResetExpires: Date,
  isActive: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
});

const db = mongoose.connection.useDb(process.env.H_STAY_DB);
const User = db.model("HStayUser", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

this is how the database is being initiated in server.js

```
const DB = `${process.env.DATABASE_LOCAL}`;
mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then((conn) => {
    console.log("Connected to DB");
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

And there's no default database declared in the URI for the mongo database.. here's the entry in the .env file

```
DATABASE_LOCAL=mongodb://localhost:27017/
```

However when I try to create a user, the user gets created in a `test` database and not in the `projectDb` database. In fact when the server loads up, this `test` database is created automatically on load. I expected the `useDb('projectDb)` option that I am implementing in the userModel to be visible to the server and expected the `projectDb` to be created on load or on receiving a createUser request.

I have been trying to get my head around this but not able to figure it out. Any advice or direction to work on would be appreciated.

Comment: The [useDb](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#Connection.prototype.useDb()) example in the docs uses `await` and `asPromise()` when connecting.  Does it behave differently with that?

Comment: when I do this in the server.js `const connection = await mongoose.createConnection(DB).asPromise();`


I get this error..
`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`.. not sure how to run an await function on the server.js.. haven't done that before.. any advise?

Comment: the way I was originally doing it, do you think I was creating a connection on the server.js on initialisatio and then when in the model I was running the `mongoose.connection.useDb('projectDb')` was I creating another connection? If so, Is there a way I can run the useDb on the same connection that I am creating on the server.js? I am not an expert on this so please excuse me if my suggestions are too basic or not logical..;-)..